# How do I connect glade signals using GtkBuilder in C#?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, glade, gtkbuilder

In python, I could just do `builder.connect_signals(self)`. It doesn't seem like this method exists in C#, and after looking at [the GtkBuilder documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Builder.html), it looks like python is the exception, rather than  the rule. How would I accomplish the same thing in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Gtk.Builder is not fully implemented in the current version of Gtk# (2.12).
This [thread](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td23463336) explains the current situation. So once Gtk# 2.14 is released, you can just      do:

```
builder.Autoconnect (this);
```

In the meantime you could use [Glade.XML](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=24@ecma:372%23XML/), and then convert your code (and glade files) as described here: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/gtk-sharp-list/2008-October/009157.html

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Any word on when 2.14 will be released?

Comment: Hmm this makes it sound like they're skipping 2.14+ in favor of 3.x:
http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpPlan#Release_plan

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your signals using method `Autoconnect`, but method that represent a signal in c# must be in form:

```
static void customMethod(object sender, EventArgs args);
```

So each field of class that you use in such method must be declared as `static`. It robs you of creating another instance of your class.

There is another way of connecting signals:

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.AddFromFile("custom.glade");
Button button = (Button)builder.GetObject("closeButton");
button.Clicked += delegate {
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your participation. Code-only answers are discouraged here as they do not provide much value for further reasers, so could you please explain why and how it works?