# How do I use gtk builder in c#

Tags: c#, gtk#

according to [How do I connect glade signals using GtkBuilder in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693454/how-do-i-connect-glade-signals-using-gtkbuilder-in-c) in 2009 developers of mono were about to implement gtk builder to c#. It's 2013 and the proposed methods are still not available. So is there any way to use it?

Since GtkBuilder replaced glade format, whole glade thing doesn't seem to be useful for c# (at least the glade editor is saving files as GtkBuilder format, which can't be read by libglade in mono)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to use GTK Builder in C# without having to use the Glade library. (I have also had success doing this in Boo, by the way; have not had success with Cobra, and have not tried [Iron]Python or [Iron]Ruby.)

One very strong reason for wanting to use GTK builder instead of the Glade library is that, AFAIK, Glade versions after 3.8 produce XML code that is compatible only with GTK+3 (http://blogs.gnome.org/tvb/2011/01/15/the-glade-dl/). Plus, I would think that using GTK Builder would allow one to use an XML file generated by virtually any GUI builder that produces an appropriate definition.

Okay, so here's the solution adapted to C# from the MonoBasic example at: http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Hello_World. I used the GUI definitions in that example to create a GUI in Glade 3.14.2, and then simply saved the file as 'togglebuttons.xml'.

togglebuttons.cs:

```
using Gtk;
using System;

class ToggleButtons
{
    public ToggleButtons()
    {
        Gtk.Application.Init();
        Builder Gui = new Builder();
        Gui.AddFromFile("togglebuttons.xml");
        Gui.Autoconnect(this);
        Gtk.Application.Run();
    }

    static void onDeleteEvent(object o, DeleteEventArgs args)
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    static void onExitButtonEvent(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        new ToggleButtons();
    }
}
```

And here's the XML file generated by Glade, togglebuttons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
<!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
<object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Toggle Buttons</property>
    <signal name="delete-event" handler="onDeleteEvent" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
    <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
        <object class="GtkToggleButton" id="togglebutton1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Button 1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
        </object>
        <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
        </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
        <object class="GtkToggleButton" id="togglebutton2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Button 2</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
        </object>
        <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
        </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
        <object class="GtkSeparator" id="separator1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        </object>
        <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
        </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
        <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Close</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="onExitButtonEvent" swapped="no"/>
        </object>
        <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
        </packing>
        </child>
    </object>
    </child>
</object>
</interface>
```

HTH :-)

Comment: How is this possible? The XML file demands gtk+3.0, while Gtk# 2.12 wraps gtk+2... I've tried this myself and throws an exception because of that. When I manipulate the file, it seems that the XML format GtkBuilder# expects is different from the one generated by Glade 3.20... Maybe it was possible before (though I cannot see how), but is impossible now.

Comment: It is not impossible. And, you have stated exactly why you are having a problem, "The XML file demands gtk+3.0, while Gtk# 2.12 wraps gtk+2." You need to use the "-pkg:" switch to compile against Gtk#3, not Gtk#2.

Comment: All right, I apologize, I didn't know about Gtk#3 as a NuGet package. Strange electrion, makes me think it is not completed... is it? Okay, I tried on Windows installing MSYS2, and then gtk+3 with pacman, with no luck (I use both Windows and Linux). Probably will work without glitches in Linux. Maybe I have to point Xamarin Studio to the libraries somehow? Haven't found how...

Comment: I've been able to complete the work in linux! You need to install gtk+3 in your system, open monodevelop and add the gtk#3 nuget package to the project, and it works.
I haven't been able to repeat the success in Windows, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know whether the builder object is implemented or not since I'm also new to GTK#, but the Autoconnect() method indeed works for the Glade.XML objects and that is how I connect the signals in my glade xml. Below is a working example of a simple helloworld c# program which uses Autoconnect for signals:

(I've got GTK# 2.12.20, and Glade 3.4.3)

using System;
using Gtk;
using Glade;

namespace textPad
{
    public class GladeApp
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new GladeApp ();
        }

```
    public GladeApp(){
        //System.Console.WriteLine ("Hello GTK");
        //System.Console.Read ();
        Gtk.Application.Init ();

        Glade.XML gxml = new XML (null,@"textPad.FirstTextpad.glade","window1",null);

        gxml.Autoconnect (this);


        Gtk.Application.Run ();
        //return 0;
    }

    public void btnExit_clicked_cb(System.Object sender,System.EventArgs e)
    {
        close (null,null);
    }

    public void close(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What difference does it  make if you use glade instead of gtk-builder? Ultimately, your GUI app runs and thats what matter. Are there any specific advantages of using gtk-builder instead of Glade.XML in C#?

Comment: The difference is that latest glade doesn't even support this obsolete format. All these new tools are producing GtkBuilder format, so I can't use them. (produced xml files aren't compatible)

Comment: Hmmn. Is something radically changed in the new glade (such as new controls, etc.), that you cannot use glade version 3.4? If you use this version and generate the .glade files, I'm sure it will autoconnect.

Comment: I don't know - the version I have is ubuntu default version, I can try some other versions, but currently I am using monodevelop stetic as alternative

Comment: Yes, glade on ubuntu has moved on to 3.12. If you really want to use autoconnect, you can try this workaround: If you have a spare windows machine or a virtual-machine, install glade 3.4 there and use it to design your GUI. Once done, you can copy the .glade files to your ubuntu machine where you can autoconnect.

Comment: However, if you are happy with stetic, then there is no reason to use glade at all. I've found stetic to contain a more comprehensive bag of controls than glade, but then I don't have the glade latest version.

Comment: On a different note, your ubuntu glade version must be giving you the option to save in gtkbuilder or libglade format. Have you even tried saving in libglade format and then "autoConnect"ing ?

Comment: Reade answer to this SO question and you will know how to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599394/convert-gtkglade-to-libglade-for-a-backwards-compatibility